# In CANFD, an error handling issue involved with error passive receiver and bus idle

Tags: can-bus, serial-communication

Suppose there is an error passive receiver node A and an error active transmitting node B. Suppose a transmitting error occured.
The B node:

1. sends a 6 bit dominant from bit 0-5;
2. then 8 recessive bits from bit 6-13 as error delimiter;
3. 3 recessive bits as intermission from 14-16.

As for node A:

1. after stuff error,6 recessive bits for error flag from bit 6-11;
2. expect 8 recessive error delimiter from bit 12-19.

However for node B,the transmitter may see bit 17 as the first bit of bus idle and may try to start a dominant SOF. But node A has not finished with error delimitter. Will node A see this dominant bit as an error

Description in the protocol

Comment: Please correctly format your lists; it makes the question much easier to read. There is formatting help available in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

In the CAN protocol, when a node is in the Error Passive state, it can only indicate a detected error by sending six homogeneous recessive bits. This is known as transmitting a Passive Error Flag. This prevents the error-detecting receivers from globalizing detected errors.

In the scenario you described, node B, the transmitter, may see bit 17 as the first bit of bus idle and may try to start a dominant SOF. However, node A has not finished with its error delimiter. Since node A is an Error Passive receiver, it will transmit a Passive Error Flag upon detection of an error. This means that node A will not see this dominant bit as an error because it is transmitting six homogeneous recessive bits. Therefore, node A will not be able to globalize the detected error.